# When is a group isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

A infinitely generated additive group G and its subgroup K, when they are isomorphic to each other? Is there any theorem on this?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: If the subgroup is a proper subgroup, the order of the subgroup will be less than the order of the group. Can there never exist a bijection in this case?

Comment: When there is a bijection from $G$ to $K$ which preserves the group operation.

Comment: @Pacman In the infinite case, there's no guarantee. Take $\Bbb Z$ and the proper isomorphic subgroup $2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I think it would be more interesting to ask for more examples of when a group is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself.

Answer (score 9):

There is no any general theorem to solve your problem

Clearly if a group is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself then $|G|$ must be infinite, but being infinite is not sufficient to be isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself, there exist some groups which are infinite and isomorphic to a subgroup of themselves such as $\Bbb Z$ under addition (isomorphic to the group of even integers) and $\Bbb R^+,\Bbb R^*,\Bbb Q^+,\Bbb Q^*$ under multiplication. and there are some infinite groups which are not isomorphic to a subgroups of themselves such that $\Bbb Q,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ under addition.

Answer (score 3):

Take the set of polynomials in a variable $x$ with integer coefficients, it is an infinitely generated group on the generating set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$. 
Take the proper subgroup of polynomials involving only the even powers:
It is a proper subgroup isomorphic to the whole group (it is infact isomorphic even as a ring).

Answer (score 2):

Look at these two articles:

1. Fallat, Shaun, et al. "On groups that are isomorphic to a proper subgroup." Mathematics Magazine 72.5 (1999): 388-391.
2. Beaumont, Ross A. "Groups with isomorphic proper subgroups." (1945): 381-387.